# Problem with MobilenetV2 implementation on mobile

Tags: android, tensorflow, mobilenet, tensorflow-lite

MobilenetV2 tflite model trained on cifar10 dataset  is expecting input image of shape 1x32x32x3(Because during training their was batch flag used) but in order to dump model into Mobile I get  32x32x3 shape images from camera  so now not able to feed data into tflite.interpreter.......any Suggestion

Answer (score 0):

A 1x32x32x3 matrix has the same number of elements as a 32x32x3 matrix, so you can feed the data from the image to the input tensor of the tflite interpreter without causing any error.

Comment: Tq... the problem was with the dimensions of byte buffers created